# Confusing return statement

Tags: java, floating-point, operator-precedence

I'm failing to understand exactly what the IF statement is doing, from what I can see it is checking if the variable `x` is equal to the int `0`. If this is `true` the ABSOLUTE value of the variable `y` is returned... this is when I lose the plot, why would the return statement then go on to include `<= ESPILON`? Surely this means less than or equal to the value of epsilon? if so how is that working? If it doesn't mean that then what does it mean?

(JAVA CODE)

```
final double EPSILON = 1E-14;
if (x == 0)
    return Math.abs(y) <= EPSILON;
```

Comment: Vincent, I don't understand the purpose in retagging this as floating-point-inaccuracy if you are not going to say anything about why it relates to that. In any case, FP inaccuracy is primarily a problem for an equality comparison, not for <=. Retagged.

Comment: isn't that the point though? This was done to *avoid* FP inaccuracy - the tag seems quite appropriate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Floating-point math is by its nature inaccurate, so rather than testing for equivalence (which is always a bad idea), instead the developer has chosen a small number (1x10^-14 in this case) as the acceptable tolerance for proximity to zero. The return statement returns a comparison, so what this will do is take the absolute value of y, and return true if and only if it is sufficiently close to zero, where sufficiently close is defined by EPSILON.

Comment: The key point here is that it is returning a boolean, not the absolute value of y

Answer (score 5):

It returns true if the absolute value of y is <= EPSILON, and false otherwise. The <= is evaluated before the return statement. This code is equivalent:

```
if(x == 0)
{
   boolean ret = Math.abs(y) <= EPSILON;
   return ret;
}
```

The code isn't simply read from left to right. A simpler example is

```
int x = 3 + 4 * 5;
```

After evaluating this, x is 23, not 35. The evaluation is 3 + (4*5), not (3+4)*5, because the * has a higher precedence than the +. The return statement in the original example has a very low precedence. All operators like +, -, <, >= are evaluated before it.

Answer (score 5):

The entire expression

```
Math.abs(y) <= EPSILON
```

should be evaluated first, which means the function is going to return a boolean value (true/false). Having said that, if

```
x != 0
```

then I'm not sure what will get returned.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it is checking if the variable x is equal to (well, maybe int) 0.  However, if this is true then it doesn't return the absolute value of y, it returns a boolean, the result of the <= operator.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning a boolean value.

Epsilon is a double, holding the value 1E-14.

This is the actual IF statement

```
if (x==0) {
    return MATH.abs(y) <= EPSILON;
}
```

So, what's getting returned is if the absolute value of y is less than or equals to Epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done Java in a long time but it would appear that this is actually returning a boolean (which might be implicitly cast).

I would say that if x equals 0, it returns true when the absolute value of y <= Epsilon, otherwise it returns false.

However if x doesn't equal 0 then it would return null, as no statement covers the else.

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" is that this fragment relies heavyly on operator precedence (not bad per se, but sometimes it can be confusing).

[Here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) you can find a list of all java operators with their precedence, and [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence) for comparison the same table for C/C++

Comment: Precedence here is really easy.  Method calls always have very high precedence.  After that there is only one operator remaining.

return is not an operator -- it's a statement like if or while that accepts an expression.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to this

```
return (Math.abs(y) <= EPSILON);
```

which should have been added to the code for clarity.  As has been mentioned, it returns a boolean.

An alternatives would be

```
if (Math.abs(y) <= EPSILON)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```